# Apache2 Vhost HTTP to HTTPS Redirect not working in a strange way

Tags: virtualhost, apache2

I set up HTTPS for my website for the first time today. I started with the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName website.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/website.tld

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/website.tld.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/website.tld.key

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/website.tld/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

which totally worked fine. Now I wanted the website to redirect http to https and added the following at the top:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website.tld
    ServerAlias www.website.tld
    Redirect 301 / https://website.tld
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName www.website.tld
     Redirect 301 / https://website.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

Now if I access the website from http it redirects to https, BUT once I'm on the https site I get an error from Chrome saying "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".
Can somebody help?

Comment: Why do you have added a second `<VirtualHost *:443>` with redirect? You only need the redirect in the non-SSL VHost. Remove the last 4 lines. And `ServerName`, `ServerAlias` should have the same values in both VHosts.

Comment: Ah, now i get it. One 443 VHost for `www` and one for `non-www`. Yes, that's of course a valid solution if configured correctly (missing certificate). I would have used a `RewriteRule` instead. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this entry

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName www.website.tld
     Redirect 301 / https://website.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

is that you have omitted the TLS certificate for that VirtualHost. That creates a plain HTTP virtualhost on the HTTPS port.

That config should look more like this

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName www.website.tld
     Redirect 301 / https://website.tld

     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/www.website.tld.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/www.website.tld.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Or when the existing certificate  website.tld.crt is also valid for the wwww domain, point to that file.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ServerFault! I believe Freddy is correct. Your #1 issue is that you have two separate VirtualHost definitions for port 443. Get rid of the 'www' redirect, and [use an .htaccess rule instead to redirect 'www' to the domain without the www](https://serverfault.com/questions/909200/htaccess-redirect-non-www-http-with-full-url).

As a (possibly helpful) aside, this discussion on Stack Overflow seems relevant to what you're trying to do: Note in the stackoverflow.com conversation, the OS is Ubuntu: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286707/apache-ssl-configuration-error-ssl-connection-error/27568209

Comment: Please don't recommend the use of  .htaccess files to administrators. They are [a menace](https://serverfault.com/a/780517/37681)  designed for end-users that don't have admin privileges as an admin can place every mod_rewrite rule in the main httpd.conf instead. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when - placing a redirect in a separate VirtualHost  to redirect one domain to another is perfectly fine.

Comment: Fair enough. Good point, re: setup the redirect in the <VirtualHost> rather than an .htaccess rule.